# If $p$ and $q$ are distinct odd primes, prove $2^{pq+1} \equiv 2^{p+q} \pmod {pq}$

Tags: number-theory

Please help me for this question.. I dont have any idea how to solve it... [image]

Answer (score 4):

By Fermat's Little Theorem, working modulo $p$,
$$2^{pq+1}=2^{pq}\times 2=(2^{p})^q\times2\equiv 2^q\times 2 \equiv 2^q \times 2^p =2^{p+q}  \pmod p$$
Similarly the congruence holds modulo $q$, so it holds modulo $\text{lcm}(p,q)=pq$.